# how to enable logging in angularjs 1.x

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way we can log compiler processing in angularjs 1.x ?
I'm trying to use ui-grid but for some reason nothing is displayed n no error occurred. so want to see some log on console. so was wondering if this can be enabled like in log4j...

Comment: You forgot to post the code in the question

Comment: i just want to enable console logging in angular like we in log4j so i could see how angular processes html elements and tags... i mean is it even possible or angular compiler/injector designed with logging mechanism?

Comment: Inject `$logProvider` to the `config` phase and turn it on by `$logProvider.debugEnabled(true);`

Comment: thanks :) let me try

Comment: this worked with my controller so i could write log statements for my code. however i want logs to see how angular compiler itself or for how included components/directives behave.

Comment: First thing first - Load `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js` and you'll see more detailed error messages. Next - Take a look [at this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.reloadWithDebugInfo) - Hope it helps, because I don't have any other idea :)